# Why does navigateUp() cause ViewModel to not observe one of the WorkInfo states

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have 2 activities A and B. Activity B returns some data to Activity A which is used to create a `OneTimeWorkRequest` to do something else. I'm using a ViewModel to observe changes in the WorkInfo state for this request. For example:

ActivityA.kt

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    myViewModel =
        viewModel<MyViewModel>().apply {
          observe(requestWorkInfo) {
            println(it.state)
            // expects to print: ENQUEUED, RUNNING, SUCCEEDED
          }
        }
```

The fragment in Activity A needs to `navigateUp()` to the previous fragment after it receives the data from Activity B and creates the request. For example:

MyFragment.kt

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    myViewModel.createOneTimeRequest(intent)
    this.findNavController().navigateUp()
  }
```

The problem I'm facing is that ENQUEUED is not printed when I do this - only RUNNING and SUCCEEDED are. If I remove `this.findNavController().navigateUp()`, all three states are printed as expected. My question is why is ENQUEUED not observed when I `navigateUp()` after creating the request? Is there an underlying concurrency problem associated with this? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're not using the shared ViewModel in Fragment

Comment: I am. I only have the one ViewModel.